# Crontab won't download file from FTP server using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I have a PHP script I've written to login to an FTP server, download a csv file of suppression data, and merge it with our current suppression list file.

It works perfectly when I run it from the command line.  When I set it up to run once a day in crontab, it always says that it can't download the file from the FTP server, and exits.  I've given a 777 to the directory that the script is writing the file to, so I can't imagine it would be a permissions problem.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Is there something simple I'm missing?  Below is my crontab line and my script code, if that would help in giving an answer. Thank you!

Crontab entry:

`0 8 * * * php /var/www/scripts/ftp-unsubs.php >> /var/www/scripts/logs/ftp-unsubs.log`

PHP script:

```
<?
// get latest suppression file and append to our global suppression file (loader.txt)

$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));
$ftp_server = '--hidden--';
$ftp_user_name = '--hidden--';
$ftp_user_pass = '--hidden--';
$local_file = 'unsub_dls/unsubs.' . $yesterday . '.csv';
$remote_file = 'FJM378_unsubs.' . $yesterday . '.csv';


// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

print "\n[" . date("r") . "]\n";

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
    echo "FTP connection has failed!\n";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name\n";
}

// try to download $remote_file and save to $local_file

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
  echo "Couldn't get file $remote_file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream
if (ftp_close($conn_id)) {
  print "Closed the connection to $ftp_server\n";
}


// grab new unsubs and add timestamp
print "\nProcessing file $local_file\n";

if (file_exists($local_file)) {

  $fh = fopen($local_file, 'r');

  $i = 0;
  $unsub = "";
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    $line = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "", $line);
    if ($line != "" && $line != "email") {
      $unsub .= $line . "," . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n";
      $i++;
    }
  }

  fclose($fh);

  // add unsubs to global unsub file
  $fsupp = fopen('loader.txt','a');
  fwrite($fsupp, $unsub);
  fclose($fsupp);

  print "Added $i unsubs to loader.txt\n\n";

} else {
  print "Error: file '$local_file' doesn't exist! Bailing.\n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Change `0 8 * * * php ` for `0 8 * * * /bin/php` or whatever comes from `which php`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it (it was /usr/bin/php) and it gave me the same problem... says "Couldn't get file" and exits.

Comment: So the script is execute but cannot connect. Change `$local_file = 'unsub_dls/unsubs.' . $yesterday . '.csv';` to full path?

Comment: Ha! you're kidding, it was that simple.  That worked perfectly!  Thank you a million times.

Comment: Nice to read that! Crontab always prefers full paths for everything, as no environment is loaded when executed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a username under whose credentials this task should run to your crontab entry like this:

0 8 * * * **root** php /var/www/scripts/ftp-unsubs.php >> /var/www/scripts/logs/ftp-unsubs.log